# jQuery $(this) Not Working On Mobile Devices

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5

I created my own date picker like this:

```
$.fn.datepicker = function (options = {}) {
    var el = $(this);
    //rest of code
}
```

In `$(document).ready()` I initialize it like this:

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    noWeekends: true,
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
        $("#end_date").val($F("date"));
    }
});
```

Works great on a computer but on a mobile device, `$(this)` is undefined. I got around it by passing the ID of the field in the options and doing this:

```
$.fn.datepicker = function (options = {}) {
    var forcedID = options["id"];
    var el = $(this);
    if(!el && forcedID) {
        el = $("#"+forcedID);
    }
    //rest of code
}
```

Even though I found a workaround, why is `$(this)` undefined on mobile devices?

I'm not using jQuery Mobile. I'm using jQuery and Bootstrap 5.

Comment: How is that error being reported? I ask because I have little experience debugging directly on mobile devices.

Comment: I'm actually using the Responsive Design Mode in Safari which simulates mobile devices.

Comment: I sure wouldn't think you'd get different JavaScript values from that. I use Chrome's analogous feature all the time. Are you sure something else isn't going on?